# Using serial port interactively with Haskell

Tags: haskell, serial-port, nxt

I'm trying to send a message via the serial port to a Lego NXT using Haskell's interactive mode but I cannot figure out how to use the [serialport](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/serialport/0.4.5/doc/html/System-Hardware-Serialport.html) functions correctly.

I have a message that should play a tone on the NXT which is of type `ByteString`

```
> let message = pack ([6, 0 ,0, 3, 224, 1, 208, 7]::[Word8])
```

I can open the serial port using `openSerial`.

```
openSerial :: FilePath -> SerialPortSettings -> IO SerialPort
> let mybrick = openSerial "/dev/tty.NXT-DevB" defaultSerialSettings
```

But then I get stuck. How should I use the `send` function?

```
send :: SerialPort -> B.ByteString -> IO Int
> send mybrick message
```

This gives my the following error message.

```
<interactive>:31:6:
    Couldn't match expected type `SerialPort'
                with actual type `IO SerialPort'
    In the first argument of `send', namely `mybrick'
    In the expression: send mybrick message
    In an equation for `it': it = send mybrick message
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to *sequence* your `Monad` computations. I'll write it generally and simply then specifically for your situation.

---

The problem you have is you have a function `f :: A -> IO B` and another function `g :: B -> IO C` which feel like they ought to be combinable, but aren't quite---the second function needs a *plain* `B`, not the `IO B` that the first one returns.

This is exactly where the power of `Monad`s comes into play. Knowing that `IO` is a monad, we can use a function like `(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c` to combine these `Monad`ic functions. In fact, already, `f >=> g :: A -> IO C` like we require.

We can also use `do` notation which would require us to "bind" the return type of `f` and then apply that to `g` to get the output.

```
\a -> do b <- f a
         g b
```

which gives us a function of type `A -> IO C` again. In fact, this `do` notation is basically the definition of `(>=>)`.

---

So how does this apply in your particular circumstance? Well,

```
let mybrick = openSerial "/dev/tty.NXT-DevB" defaultSerialSettings
```

gives you a `mybrick :: IO SerialPort` value. In order to use `send :: SerialPort -> ByteString -> IO Int` we need to "unwrap" `mybrick` from the `IO` `Monad`. So we can use `do` notation

```
do sp <- mybrick
   send sp message
```

Or, to make everything neater, we can just run the entire computation using `do` notation

```
do mybrick <- openSerial "/dev/tty.NXT-DevB" defaultSerialSettings
   send mybrick message
```

Comment: I finally got it to work! Had to turn on multiline input on ghci (:set +m) but i found it easier to use `send mybrick $ message`. I also got the message wrong, were missing two message length bytes in the beginning but now my NXT play a tone :D

Comment: I've literally never used `+m` before—that's a good find! Glad you got it working!

Comment: Also, `f a b c d $ e` is identical to `f a b c d e`, so `send mybrick message` should be the same as `send mybrick $ message`.

Comment: Hey, you're right :) Well, what I was supposed to say was that I could just use `mybrick <- openSerial "/dev/tty.NXT-DevB" defaultSerialSettings` skipping the do notation and the need for multiline input.

Comment: Yeah, and it's also good to be familiar with how to translate between `do` notation and the regular `(>>=)` and `(>=>)` operators.

Answer (score 2):

`openSerial path settings` is an IO action, which produces a serial port. To get access to the serial port, you have to execute that action inside the IO monad. Your `main` could look something like this:

```
main = do 
    mybrick <- openSerial "/dev/tty.NXT-DevB" defaultSerialSettings
    let message = pack ([0, 3, 224, 1, 208, 7] :: [Word8])
    send mybrick message
```

The difference is, that the `let` binding just creates a new name for whatever comes after the equals sign. In this case, this leads to `mybrick` having type `IO SerialPort`, just like the error message says.